# Help in figuring out what might be wrong with the mvc-mini-profiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

This is the Method that is being profiled

```
    public IList<Product> GetPagedProducts(int page)
    {

        const string sql = @"
                SELECT * FROM
                (
                    SELECT a.*, rownum r__
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT * FROM PRODUCTHEADER
                        ORDER BY productid DESC
                    ) a
                    WHERE rownum < ((:PageNumber * :PageSize) + 1 )
                )
                WHERE r__ >= (((:PageNumber - 1) * :PageSize) + 1)";

        return OracleConnection.Query<Product>(sql, new { pageNumber = page, pageSize = 60 }).ToList();
    }
```

I am using the MvcMiniProfiler.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter() as the OracleFormatter throws a Not Implemented Exception. (v 1.9)

Thank you,
Stephen

And here is the output from the webpage after clicking on the mini-profiler tab sql link.

It looks like a bunch of junk, but there seems to be formatting applied to it, so I'm including it for Sam to check out.

601606016060160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160S60160E60160L60160E60160C60160T60160 60160*60160 60160F60160R60160O60160M601606016060160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160(601606016060160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160S60160E60160L60160E60160C60160T60160 60160a60160.60160*60160,60160 60160r60160o60160w60160n60160u60160m60160 60160r60160_60160_601606016060160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160F60160R60160O60160M601606016060160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160(601606016060160   60160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160S60160E60160L60160E60160C60160T60160 60160*60160 60160F60160R60160O60160M60160 60160P60160R60160O60160D60160U60160C60160T60160H60160E60160A60160D60160E60160R601606016060160   60160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160O60160R60160D60160E60160R60160 60160B60160Y60160 60160p60160r60160o60160d60160u60160c60160t60160i60160d60160 60160D60160E60160S60160C601606016060160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160)60160 60160a601606016060160   60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160W60160H60160E60160R60160E60160 60160r60160o60160w60160n60160u60160m60160 60160<60160 60160(60160(60160:60160P60160a60160g60160e60160N60160u60160m60160b60160e60160r60160 60160*60160 60160:60160P60160a60160g60160e60160S60160i60160z60160e60160)60160 60160+60160 60160160160 60160)601606016060160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160)601606016060160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160 60160W60160H60160E60160R60160E60160 60160r60160_60160_60160 60160>60160=60160 60160(60160(60160(60160:60160P60160a60160g60160e60160N60160u60160m60160b60160e60160r60160 60160-60160 60160160160)60160 60160*60160 60160:60160P60160a60160g60160e60160S60160i60160z60160e60160)60160 60160+60160 60160160160)60160

end of output.

Comment: Heh sorry about that :) I didn't see anything that it was relating to so I deleted it.

Comment: can you simplify your test/demo, what breaks it?